# BigQuery - Resources error when I make a SELECT FIELD but no error when I do SELECT * (on the same table)

Tags: sql, optimization, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, query-optimization

Working query: SELECT * FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table`

Not working query: SELECT id FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table`

Error I get: Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex.

I understand the error, but I don't understand why it's occuring when I change '*' to any field (id for exemple)

thank you :)

Comment: What happens if you change the name of the id field? Wondering if there might be conflict with an internal command/function. Something like id_1

Comment: What's your schema and the list of field that provide the select *?

Comment: Hi Charl, unfortunately I tired customer_id and there is no change

Comment: My suspicion is that the table you are selecting from is in fact a logical view, and the view itself is already near the threshold of planning complexity.  There's enough of a planning difference between the two forms to cause the error in the explicit column projection case but not the full projection case.  This may indicate some simplification of the logical view is warranted (which may itself be referencing other views).